# How to handle data format for a DateTime field in the model for ASP.NET razor page with Arabic culture

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, razor, data-annotations

While I set the Arabic language at that time my modifyOn/createOn date property throws an invalid state (for English it's working fine).

```
if (model.isValid)
```

returns false even when date is valid, but in Arabic character below is the screenshot of validate mode of all property.

Property which I define in my model

[image]

`.cshtml` `HiddenFor` HTML markup:

[image]

Screenshot of validation:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with unrecognized dates due to different calendar formats. You can add `DateTimeFormat` to specific `CultureInfo`, like this:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ar-AE");
var dateformat = new DateTimeFormatInfo
{
    LongDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
};
culture.DateTimeFormat = dateformat;

var supportedCultures = new[]
{
    culture
};

app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture),
    SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
    SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
});
```

My test code in controller:

```
public IActionResult Create(TestModel model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        foreach(var item in model.Input.BookRoles)
        {
            var rqf = Request.HttpContext.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>();
            var culture = rqf.RequestCulture.Culture;
            var DataString = item.CreatedOn.ToLongDateString();
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

Test Result:

[image]